# Facebook comments on site

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I added facebook comments on my site but I still can't moderate it. I did everything like most pages advise. First of all I created application and made it public. Then I put SDK script from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments). (there is an 'app id' inside the script) and put

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

to my `content.php` file in wordpress site (so every post will have comments).

After all I added to head section

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}"/>
```

which 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is my facebook id. (I also tried with 'app id' way). However I can't modify comments. Also I can't see any comments when I go to [facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/).

It seems like facebook doesn't connect my site with this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've fixed it. Instead of admin id, I used my profile name in the content area. You can find it opening your profile and see at link.

`<meta property="fb:admins" content="your_profile_name"/>`